# How to update customer data faster and more efficiently

Tags: magento-2.1, customer-attribute

I am writing a script to add values to a custom attribute for 10 thousand customers. I have two questions here.

1. when we update custom attribute values for product, we can use:

   ```
   $resource = $product->getResource();
   $product->setData($attribute, $value);
   $resource->saveAttribute($product,$attribute);
   ```

   which is very fast. 
   But as for customer, it does not have getResource() method. The only way I know is:
       $this->_customerRepository->save($customer);
   which is very very slow. so how can I update the customers values faster?
2. when I update these values in bulk, I wrote the script as followings, it was running fine at the start, but then throws exception:
   (/chroot/home/.../html/vendor/magento/framework/Exception/FileSystemException.php): failed to open stream: Too many open files in /chroot/home/.../html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444
   I Googled this problem and someone says it is relevant to the settings of sever. However, since we rent the server and have no authorization to change it, how should I modify my code and make it use less resources?

   ```
          protected function updateAttributes($customersListData,$output) {
             $time_start = microtime(true);
             $totalLength = sizeof($customersListData);
             foreach ($customersListData as $customerIndex => $singleCustomerData) {
               try {
                 $id = $singleCustomerData['id'];
                 $customer = $this->_customerRepository->getById($id);

                 $arrayKeys = array_keys($singleCustomerData);
                 array_shift($arrayKeys);
                 foreach ($arrayKeys as $singleKey) {
                   if (empty($singleCustomerData[$singleKey])) {
                     $singleCustomerData[$singleKey] = "";
                   }
                   $time_now = microtime(true);
                   $time_used = $time_now - $time_start;
                   $finished_records = (int)$customerIndex + 1;
                   $output->writeln("Updating attribute: ".$singleCustomerData[$singleKey].". " .$finished_records ."/".$totalLength." done. will finsih in: ". round($time_used / $finished_records * ($totalLength - $finished_records), 0). "s.");
                   $customer->setData($singleKey, $singleCustomerData[$singleKey]);
                 }
                 $this->_customerRepository->save($customer);
                 unset($customer);
               } catch (\Exception $e) {
                 $output->writeln($e->getMessage());
                 continue;
               }
             }
           }
   ```